# How to select row with first occurrence of column value?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
date_table(date, country_id, policy_id, ...)
country_table(country_id, country, ...)
policy_table(policy_id, policy, ...)
```

I want to select the `country` and `policy` for the earliest date in the table.

So if I have:

```
UK | Taxation| 01/01/2021
UK | Brexit  | 02/01/2021
FR | Travel  | 05/01/2021
```

I want to return this:

```
UK | Taxation| 01/01/2021
FR | Travel  | 05/01/2021
```

However, if I try to use `GROUP BY` I get an error since I don't include `policy`. If I do include it, I get the earliest date for `country` AND `policy`, which is not what I want. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT country
     , policy
     , MIN(date)
  FROM date_table AS d
  JOIN country_table AS c 
    ON d.country_id = c.country_id
  JOIN policy_table AS p 
    ON p.policy_id = d.policy_id
 WHERE date IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY country, policy
 ORDER 
    BY date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *dense_rank* window function to solve this problem

you can modify your query as follows

```
select country, policy, date 
    from(
        SELECT country, policy, date, dense_rank() over(partition by country order by date) as rnk
        FROM date_table AS d
        JOIN country_table AS c ON d.country_id = c.country_id
        JOIN policy_table AS p ON p.policy_id = d.policy_id
        WHERE date IS NOT NULL) tmp 
 where rnk = 1
order by date;
```

Comment: This works, but if there are multiple rows with the same country and date, it shows them all. (eg. `UK|Tax|01/01/2021|` and `UK|Fishing|01/01/2021`

Comment: You can add policy in that order by, after that date within the subquery, but I am not sure if that's a good way, since having duplicate records is still a valid answer according to your requirement

Comment: You were right, adding policy into the `order by` solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try a query like this **its not tested!**

```
SELECT c.country, p.policy, d.date
FROM (
  SELECT country, MIN(date) AS mdate
  FROM date_table
  GROUP BY date,country
) as grouped
LEFT JOIN date_table AS d ON d.country = grouped.country AND d.date = grouped.mdate
JOIN country_table AS c  ON d.country_id = c.country_id
JOIN policy_table AS p  ON p.policy_id = d.policy_id
ORDER BY d.date;
```